# angularjs divide content to different paragraphs

Tags: angularjs, resources, paragraph

I got my data from a json file like

$http.get('json/about.json').success(function($scope.about = data;}

say in data I have:
Hello world paragraph. How do you do paragraph. How are you paragraph.

I want to display these in 3 different html p s. How do I do that?

1>I could divide data into data1, data2 and data3, but this breaks data integrity.
2>I could also put  html p /p  into data, but this mixes views with models.

Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: How about using `str.split('.')` to divide the data to three pieces?

Comment: thanks. it is also a good and fast way to do this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the paragraphs in an array property called paragraphs:

```
var data = {
    paragraphs: ['Hello world paragraph.', 'How do you do paragraph.', 'How are you paragraph.']
};

$scope.paragraphs = data.paragraphs;
```

View:

```
<p ng-repeat="paragraph in paragraphs">{{paragraph}}</p>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aJgCbX8PMg2pOE2KvQUC?p=preview)

Comment: I did try, but I am still not qualified to vote. By the way, could you add a json file? I am not really sure how would you save the data in a json file?

Comment: Thanks. If you are happy with the answer you could mark it as the solution.

Comment: could you create a json file and put the array in json? I want to learn how to read it from json if its an array. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Here is a Plunkr using a .json file: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/00txDGrTLDxs8EqSC6Ys?p=preview)